# Images vertically aligned using display:inline-block not aligning

Tags: html, css

The images display one atop another, not in a horizontal line, no idea why.
Just need them to align horizontally.....

HTML

```
<div id="detail_image_wrapper">
    <div class="detail_images">
        <img id="left_detail" src="images/LeftDetailImg.png" alt="Phone image">
    </div>

    <div class="detail_images">
        <img id="centre_detail" src="images/CentreDetailImg.png" alt="Phone image">
    </div>

    <div class="detail_images">
        <img id="right_detail" src="images/RightDetailImg.png" alt="Phone image">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.detail_images {
    width: 203px;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a width property to the images, not just the image container. Otherwise the images will not resize to fit into their container and they will overflow it, causing them to overlap. Example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h8SMN/1/)

Add this to your CSS:

```
.detail_images img {
    width: 203px;
}
```

You can adjust the width of the images as needed.